# Sampling ±50 V signal with differential ADC

Tags: adc, sampling, programmable-gain-amplifier

I am looking to use a differential ADC to sample a ±50 V signal with this ADC [here (AD9238)](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9238.pdf). What are some ways to bump the signal down to a level the ADC can read?

Signals would be sampled at >= 20MHz. Could think of it as an oscilloscope. No real constraints on impedances, but should keep errors and noise to a minimum. Looking to find single supply solutions to keep it portable and compact. Possibly some instrumentation amplifier?

Comment: Depends on what input impedance you need for your 50V signal, and what output impedance you need to provide for your ADC. Do you have a specification for what you must be able to do with the situation you are in?

Comment: Can you accept the inaccuracies resulting from a resistor divider made from uncalibrated and unmatched resistors?

Comment: What signal bandwidth? What signal impedance?

Comment: The real issue with an external divider is that you lose *a lot* of your CMRR in the resistor mismatch. Or go to some people like vishay precision with a fat wad of cash to get a calibrated differential attenuator

Comment: There are ADS131E08  boards on Ali, supposedly with schematics on PanBaidu, ff you have a Chinese friend.

Comment: @Justme I added some edits. Pretty much like a mini oscilloscope. I just don't know the best way to bring down the voltage to something an ADC can handle.

Comment: If you insist on using that ADC, then you will probably need to use an op-amp to buffer the incoming signal, and that op-amp will need to have bipolar supplies. Maybe, if you don't need DC coupling, you can get away with a passive attenuator. The inputs on that ADC must be no more than a few hundred mV above VDD and no more than a few hundred mV below GND. So you can't just attenuate your bipolar input signal. You also need to offset it to be centered at VDD/2.

Answer (score 1):

This is one topology, but like the comments say, it depends on your impedances and requirements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHsHd6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. While this would work, I'm not sure that it would be appropriate because of signal noise and any discrepancies among the actual resistor values.

Comment: If V1 is 50 V, then the common mode voltage will be 25 V, and will blow up the ADC, unless we assume that the input signal ground is not connected to ADC ground.